# Angular Ngrx - Animate element when removed

Tags: css, angular, animation, ngrx

I have a component with a selector called folder$ and a property tasks that's an array.

```
this.folder$.subscribe(res=> this.tasks =res.tasks)
```

In the HTML I have an ngfor like this

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks (click)="removeTask(task)">{{task.name}}</div>
```

The removeTask is a call like this:

```
this.taskService.removeTask(task.id).subscribe(
res => { this.store.dispach(TaskAction.remove({task});}
```

And in the reducer

```
on(TaskAction.remove, (state, action)=> {
let tasks = state.tasks.filter(el => el.id !== action.task.id;
return {
 ...state,
 tasks: tasks}
});
```

Is possible to animate from left to right the delete of an element when I filter an array?

Comment: Have you looked at the angular animations guide? [docs]( https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animating-entering-and-leaving-a-view ) It is nice because it handles elements leaving the DOM. it will be like  [@fadeInOut]="'in'" that you add to your div on the *ngFor

Comment: I tried...without ngrx it works...but the problem is the reducer and the changing state...

Comment: interesting. if something triggers the binding to change, then it should animate.